# Importing strings from a file not equivalent to identical user input?

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I'm working on importing two separate files the first file which is my problem imports the users input from a .txt file to be searched in a binary tree imported from a second file which I check for a substring matching the user input and when entering the input manually the string exists but when using the file input even though it tells me what I'm typing is identical to what is being inputed autonomously it still gives me error for the file input. I know unpon importation that their can be invisible characters imported, how can I get rid of them?

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open ("sequences.txt"); //infile.open (filename.c_str()
string temp;

    while(!infile.eof()) // To get you all the lines.
    {

        getline(infile, temp, '\n');
        sequences.push_back(temp); // Saves the line in STRING.
        size++;
    }
infile.close();
```

}

Comment: That isn't enough information.  The code you posted works pretty well, but doesn't seem related to the text of your question.

Comment: You're using the results of `getline` without verifying that the function actually worked.  (And of course, the fact that `infile.eof()` returns `false` doesn't mean that there is still data you can read.)  Try `while ( getline( infile, temp, '\n' ) )`.

Comment: Please use punctuation, you can take some here: .........,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::;;;;;;;(((((()))))))

Comment: seemed like the problem happens somewhere else

Comment: I posted the code up for an idea, its working code (not the complete code) and it imports my file into a vector array, but the strings in the vector do not respond as equivalent to an inputed string for example it says "Hello" != "Hello"  is what I mean

Comment: Couldn't that be a problem with windows \r\n line endings?

Comment: @SxMZ What are the differences?  The `==` operator requires exact equality; it can easily get confused, for example, if the strings are using different normalization forms (for UTF-8).  And of course, just viewing the strings doesn't guarantee anything either, since different characters can have the same glyph.  (In one of the fonts I frequently use, the digit zero and the capital letter O are indistiguishable.)

Comment: @IvanIshchenko If he's reading both in text mode, it shouldn't matter.  And if he's reading one input in text mode, and the other in binary, there's no reason for him to assume that they are the same.